# Create table in sql server with input parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a table in SQL server via stored procedure.

Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
create procedure test @Title nvarchar(50), @number int @chapter int
as
begin
  declare @nam nvrachar(50)
  set nam=@Title
  if exists(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME=@Title)
  begin
    update @Title set number=@number
    where chapter=@chapter
  end
  else
  begin
    create table @Title ( number int null, chapter int null );
    insert into @Title values ( @number, @chapter )
  end
end
```

Where the Title is a user selected book from the application, which is passed to SQL Server.

Comment: I think you're going to need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Seems like a really bad idea. You end up with *data* (that you'll almost certainly, at some point, want to write queries over) embedded in table *names*. Why do (you think) you want a separate table for each book?

Comment: Creating tables from a stored proc is almost alawys a big red flag that the design is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a good idea at all, do you really need one table per book?, you should have one table for books with all the titles there. Anyway, you'll need dynamic SQL for this (so first take a look [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)), so something like this should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test @Title NVARCHAR(50), @number INT, @chapter INT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) 
    SET @sql = ''

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @Title) 
    BEGIN 
        SET @sql = N'UPDATE '+QUOTENAME(@Title)+' 
                     SET number = @number 
                     WHERE chapter = @chapter;'

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@number INT, @chapter INT', @number, @chapter;
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Title) + '(number INT NULL, chapter INT NULL);
                     INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@Title) + '
                     VALUES(@number,@chapter)'

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@number INT, @chapter INT', @number, @chapter;
    END
END
```